# Функция в яваскрипте

Tags: php, javascript

как правильно сделать такую штуку в javascripte+php

```
<script>

function fight(){
<?php
if($row['fight'] == 1){

echo "setTimeout(function(){
    location.href='';
}, 1000);";

}
else{

}

?>

}
</script>
```

Comment: Так вот же она сделана, не? О.о

Comment: просто на Опере она не работает =(

Comment: Почему location.href='' - в никуда? Поставьте якорь - '#'

Comment: Значит, либо у вас `$row['fight'] != 1`, либо поменяйте `location.href='';` на что-то более реальное. Или на `location.reload();`.

Comment: либо функция fight() просто не вызывается, а лучше привести весь код

Answer (score 1):

Я-бы сделал так:

```
<script>

  if ( '<?=$row['fight']?>' == 1 ) fight = Function.prototype;
  else {
    fight = function (){ 
     setTimeout( function(){ location.href=''; }, 1000);
    }
  }

</script>
```

Но скорее так:

```
<script>

  fightFlag = <?=( $row['fight'] != 1 )?>;
  fight = (
    fightFlag ?
      Function.prototype :
      function (){ 
        setTimeout( "location.href = '';", 1000);
      }
  );

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

function fight(){
    if (<?php echo $row['fight']; ?> == 1
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.location='/';
        }, 1000);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: оффтоп: гадаем на кофейной гуще ? :)